# Capitalize function doesn't work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, capitalize

I have a website ( in WordPress ) that uses jQuery to display content ( itself " calculated " in the functions.php ). 
Basically the content that needs to be displayed based on user criterias is loaded with PHP, and displayed with jQuery.

The thing is the text is displayed in upper case, which doesn't match the design psd. I tried many functions that I found on StackOverflow, but they always made the text capitalize when the user types the data, while I need to capitalize text that is loaded in upper case, and that I need to convert to capitalized.

Here's the code I tried :

```
$.fn.capitalize = function () {
    $.each(this, function () {
        var caps = this.value;
        caps = caps.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + caps.slice(1);
        this.value = caps;
    });
    return this;
};

$.each( tbllPosts, function( key, value ) {
    $('.results').prepend('<div class="col-6"><col="row">'+
                '<a href="'+wp.url+'" class="text-center"><h3 class="title">'+value.titre+'</h3></a>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>');
    $('.title').capitalize();
});
```

The content is displayed, what doesn't work is the capitalization. Any help is appreciated, thanks !

Just checked, I have this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
```

Comment: you'd better use $(this).val() then this.value

Comment: Well, the CSS property text-transform: capitalize; doesn't work, so I figured I could transform the text before it is even displayed. Using $(this).val() instead of this.value doesn't work either, Grunt can't process it

Comment: Are you saying the text is already uppercase as it arrives? By the way, you have an error in the HTML code you're prepending; missing `div` just before `col="row"`.

Answer (score 1):

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea

You should use `text()` in your case.

Also, you do not send any arguments to your function. That's why it returns undefined.

I simplified your code ( since you didn't share any html ) so i can make a working example.

I also used `trim()` to remove the white space from the beginning of the text so that `charAt(0)` will return the first letter not a white-space.

Check below

```js
$.fn.capitalize = function(t) {

  $.each(t, function() {
    let caps = t.text().trim();
    caps = caps.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + caps.slice(1);
    t.text(caps)
  });
  return this;
};


const title = $('.title')
$.fn.capitalize(title);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="title">
  capitalize me
</p>
```

P.S. what do you mean by `Well, the CSS property text-transform: capitalize; doesn't work,` ? it doesn't get applied ? have you check the dev inspector ?

Comment: He means that `capitalize` does not lowercase letters that are already uppercase.

Comment: Grunt can't process the file, because "Warning: Uglification failed.
Unexpected token: name (caps).", I tried adding a semi colon, but it still doesn't work. And about the CSS, the property is recognised, there's no error or something, but it doesn't apply ( lowercase applies though ). Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it differently and instead of trying to update the text after its inserted - I would pass the titre through the capitlization function as a straight javascript function.

Its difficult since I don't know the data structure you are working with, but I have dodgied something up to pass the value to the function as it is being prepended to the results div. I also provided a few strings that have different capitalization to show the returned values are correctly capitlized.

```js
var tbllPosts = [
  {url: "url1", titre: "sample string 1"},
  {url: "url2", titre: "sample String 2"},
  {url: "url3", titre: "SAMPLE STRING 3"}
];


tbllPosts.forEach(function(post){
    $('.results').prepend('<div class="col-6"><col="row"><a href="'+post.url+'" class="text-center"><h3 class="title">'+ capitalize(post.titre)+'</h3></a></div></div>');
});

function capitalize (str) {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results"></div>
```

Note that if you want to capitalise the first letter of each word in the string - simply split the string at the space " " and pass each word through the function.

```js
var tbllPosts2 = [
      {url: "url1", titre: "sample string 1"},
      {url: "url2", titre: "sample String 2"},
      {url: "url3", titre: "SAMPLE STRING 3"}
    ];


    tbllPosts2.forEach(function(post){
        $('.results2').prepend('<div class="col-6"><col="row"><a href="'+post.url+'" class="text-center"><h3 class="title">'+ titleCase(post.titre)+'</h3></a></div></div>');
    });


function titleCase(str) {
 var strArr = str. split(' ');
 var newStrArr=[];
 strArr.forEach(function(word){
  newStrArr.push(capitalize(word))
})

return newStrArr.join(' ');
}
 


function capitalize (str) {
   return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results2"></div>
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually converts the rest of the letters in the word to lowercase.

Comment: Its actually something I had to do for work, so was aware of it. Thanks for noticing @MrLister

Comment: Yes, I had to reread the OP's question a couple of times before I realised that the text was uppercase to begin with. That explains why neither the CSS property `text-transform` nor the OP's own JavaScript worked to do what they wanted.